# how do I stop blender from randomly creating multiple (often disconnected) vertexs in the same place? ver 2.82a

Tags: mesh, vertices, workflow

While trying to create a low poly standing model I keep finding (while loop subdividing or while grabbing individual vertexes) a face has been lifted off with two (often) disconnected vertexes overlapping the same spot. The model seems to keep doing this in spots I'm not working on even.

I'm not sure, is this a bug?

Comment: I've not observed double vertices appearing by themselves, but there are plenty of ways to introduce them accidentally. Without knowing what you did it'll be hard to say how they might've got there, but a common way is by canceling two-part operations like extrude+move and duplicate+move.

Answer (score 1):

Go to mesh > clean up > merge by distance... figured it out but any idea why it happens?

Comment: You might extrude (E) mesh and just right click at it. It will create duplicated vertices, merge by distance help to clean them up